# Как добавить исключение для метода split?

Tags: javascript, массивы, строки, split

Необходимо из простого абзаца создать массив слов, но в данном абзаце может быть места, где пользователь ввел пробел несколько раз. Тем самым массив будет выглядеть так: `["Я", "изучаю", "", "", "JavaScript"]`

```js
let str = 'Я изучаю   JavaScript';

let arr = str.split(' ');

console.log(arr);
```

Как этого избежать? Подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: Надо использовать регулярку. Split это позволяет делать

Comment: На всякий случай: самый надёжный способ разбивать текст на слова — это [Intl.Segmenter](https://habr.com/ru/post/518900/). Если, конечно, ваша среда исполнения уже его поддерживает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) может принимать в качестве параметра регулярное выражение.

В данном случае, для разбиения по пробельным символам подойдет `\s+`, учитывающая в качестве разделителя один или несколько пробельных символов подряд.

```js
let str = 'Я изучаю   JavaScript';

let arr = str.split(/\s+/);

console.log(arr);
```